# Touchscreen right click emulation doesn't work

Tags: xorg, xinput, emulation

I have a touchscreen device for which I have enabled third button emulation in `xinput`:

```
Device 'ft5x_ts':
...
Evdev Third Button Emulation (257): 1
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (258): 750
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (259):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (260):   20
...
```

([full log](http://dimag0g.hd.free.fr/owncloud/index.php/s/PjS5alhfYLFQeKe))

However, the emulation doesn't work - the right button click events never appear. Here's the sample of `xev` output:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2058845, (94,90), root:(96,117),
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2059658, (94,89), root:(96,116),
state 0x100, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2060101, (94,89), root:(96,116),
state 0x100, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2060101, (94,89), root:(96,116),
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

As you can see, the interval between `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` is greater than 750 ms, and the pointer movement is below the 20 pix threshold, yet `xev` reports button 1 to be pressed, not button 3.

Ironically, when I configure my USB mouse in the [same way](http://dimag0g.hd.free.fr/owncloud/index.php/s/efpboTlVLCsNeP5), long clicks on button 1 do emulate button 3:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2870367, (48,82), root:(50,109),
state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2870422, (49,81), root:(51,108),
state 0x400, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 45, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x44, subw 0x0, time 2870590, (49,81), root:(51,108),
state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES
```

Can anyone help me out, perhaps point to some anomalies I didn't notice?

PS. Third button emulation [used to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224257/how-to-disable-xorg-right-click-emulation-at-runtime) with my touchscreen under Debian Wheezy, and stopped working when I upgraded to Jessie. For now, I reverted my last backup to get Wheezy installation back, but I still need a solution as Wheezy is phasing out.

Comment: Is there any difference if you crank up `Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (260):` to say, 50?

Comment: @Leathe Nope. Besides, 20 pixels is already quite a lot of threshold, sometimes small scroll/drag actions are difficult to perform because of it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=121602) and [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=115567), right click emulation is a common issue in Debian Jessie, not limited to a particular distribution. A workaround which worked for me (on a 10-point touchscreen) is to use [twofing](http://plippo.de/p/twofing) utility:

```
git clone https://github.com/Plippo/twofing
sudo apt-get install build-essential libx11-dev libxtst-dev libxi-dev x11proto-randr-dev libxrandr-dev
cd twofing; make
./twofing /dev/input/eventXX
```

`eventXX` is the device corresponding to the touchscreen, which can be found with `xinput list`. The right click event is performed by two-finger click, and as a bonus you'll get the scrolling gesture (two-finger drag) and zoom-in/zoom-out gesture (two-finger pinch). I didn't try `twofing` with a resistive touchscreen, but I suppose it will not work since resistive touchscreens don't support multitouch.